# Assign query result to variable and access it from other file

Tags: bash, shell, db2

I have two files namely `file1.sh` and `file2.sh`.

The `file1.sh` contains the DB2 query, the query return the total number of employees in the employee table.

Now I want to assign the total number of employees into a variable within the file `file1.sh`.

**File 1**:

```
#!/bin/bash
#database connection goes here
echo The total number employees: 
db2 -x "select count(*) from employee"
```

When i run above file that display the total number of employees.

But

I want to store that total into some variable and want it to access from another file that is `file2.sh`.

**File 2**:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Here i want to use total number of employees 
#Variable to be accessed here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following two scripts, *driver.sh* and *child.sh*:

**driver.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=`./child.sh syscat.tables`
echo "Number of tables:  ${RESULT}"
cnt=`./child.sh syscat.columns`
echo "Number of columns:  ${RESULT}"
```

**child.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
db2 connect to pocdb > /dev/null 2>&1

cnt=`db2 -x "select count(*) from ${1}"`

db2 connect reset > /dev/null 2>&1
db2 terminate > /dev/null 2>&1

echo ${cnt}
```

**results**

```
[db2inst1@dbms stack]$ ./driver.sh 
Number of tables:  474
Number of columns:  7006

[db2inst1@dbms stack]$ ./child.sh syscat.columns
7006
```

Comment: Is there any online terminal to check this?

Comment: You can run driver.sh from the command line.  You can also run ./child.sh from the command line, passing in the parameter, like syscat.columns.  I added an example of running child.sh in my answer.

Comment: Can i use `cnt` in driver.sh file?

Comment: The variable, cnt, in child.sh can be accessed in the variable RESULT, or whatever else you would like to call RESULT in driver.sh.

Comment: So can you edit your answer according to that. I mean use `cnt` in driver.sh file an display the count of records over that file.

Comment: I changed `RESULTS` to `cnt`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105821/discussion-between-proksch-ibm-and-mak).